# Dimension of the space of rational functions of degree $\leq n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, coding-theory

I am studying some theory of curves in order to associate them with codes and I have stuck in the following result. In my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0192690671) (p. 362 for those who own the book), it says:

If $K$ is a field, for the field $K(x)$ the set of rational functions with order $\geq -n$
at $\infty$ is the vector space of rational functions of degree $\leq n$. This is
infinite-dimensional.

**Questions.**

1. What does he mean by "the vector space of rational functions of degree $\leq n$"? Is this
   $$V:=\Bigg\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\in K(x): \deg f,\deg g \leq n\Bigg\}.$$
   In fact, what is the degree of a rational function?
2. If yes, why is this infinite dimensional?

Many thanks.

Comment: I hazard a guess that this part of the book deals with algebraic-geometry codes, and the author is discussing *the pole order* of rational functions at $\infty$. The pole order at $\infty$ of a quotient of polynomials $f(x)/g(x)$ is equal to $\deg f(x)-\deg g(x)$. Alternatively the order may refer to the multiplicity of $\infty$ as a zero of $f(x)/g(x)$ which is the negative of the pole order, i.e. $\deg g(x)-\deg f(x)$.

Comment: Dear Jyrki, thanks for your comment. Yes, your guess is correct. However, can I ask you what is the degree of a rational function the author says and if is $V$ this vector space?

Comment: The space of function of pole order (at a fixed point, infinity or not) bounded from above is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Just like in complex analysis: the sum of functions of a pole of order, say two, at a point $z_0$ cannot have a higher order pole at $z_0$ (the sum may have a lower order pole if there is cancellation).

Comment: So for example $1/x^2$ and $(x+1)/(x^3-x^2)$ both have poles of order two at $x=0$. On the other hand their sum
$$\frac{x-1}{x^3-x^2}+\frac{x+1}{x^3-x^2}=\frac{2x}{x^3-x^2}=\frac{2}{x^2-x}$$ only has a simple pole at $x=0$. Similarly $(x^2+1)$ and $x^3/(x+1)$ both have poles of order two at the infinity (numerator degee = $2+$ denominator degree). The same applies to their sum
$$(x^2+1)+\frac{x^3}{x+1}=\frac{2x^3+x^2+x+1}{x+1}.$$ OTOH, their difference would only have a simple pole at infinity because the cubic terms in the numerator cancel.